# Does OptiFine make Minecraft run smoother or slower on a low-end gaming PC?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, performance, minecraft-optifine

I have a pretty low-end PC that runs low-graphic games when it is having a good day (when it doesn't crash every two minutes).

I recently downloaded OptiFine, and after a bit of playing, I noticed that sometimes I get big lag spikes. I can't determine if OptiFine is causing the problem or if it's actually my PC just being laggy by itself. I know OptiFine promises that it makes Minecraft run smoother, but considering sometimes things lie to make it look better, I would like to know if it actually does that.

Note: I do not play with shaders or texture packs, so those aren't the reasons.

Comment: That depends on settings.

Comment: Try playing without OptiFine and see if it is less laggy. If so, it's either a problem with OptiFine or your settings.

You do not need to uninstall OptiFine to do this, you can just switch from "OptiFine 1.18 etc..." to "Latest Release".

Comment: Alright i'll try it out the next time I play minecraft and compare the gameplay, I never thought of that so thanks.

Comment: "I would like to know if it actually does that" --- Everyone I've heard says it makes the game run faster, including people i know personally, so it's not lying about that.  You might be having a bug, or your computer is just the exception for some reason.  It's supposed to help low end pcs run better too, so i hope you can figure it out.  =)

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing significant lag-spikes, it is most likely because your settings are set to high quality. Try lowering them to make the game run faster (for example, I have a Ryzen 3 CPU, and I have my render distance set to 8-chunks and it runs just fine).

Another reason is possibly because OptiFine is glitching (although based on my experience with OptiFine, it is rare for it to glitch out).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using OptiFine, and instead using Fabric + Sodium (and other mods). [Fabulously Optimized](https://modrinth.com/modpack/fabulously-optimized) is a good modpack.

If you have specific Forge mods you need to use, I recommend not playing with them, as Forge performance sucks.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! We’re a little different from other sites; this isn’t a discussion forum, but a Q&A site. Please check out our short [tour]. We reserve the answer space for answers that directly address the question. Your post seems to have some useful information, but it doesn’t answer the question clearly. Could you please [edit] your post to more directly address the question? Otherwise, [it may be deleted.](//arqade.com/help/deleted-answers)